# How to use join instead of select using mysql?

Tags: mysql

i want to find the sum of the items for the comp_id = 2

what i am trying to do?
i have two tables namely purchaseditems and item. both have comp_id in common. now i have to find the sum of items for the comp_id = 2.

below is how the tables look

[image]

As seen from above table i am expecting the sum to be 13.

so i have used the query below to get the sum of items for comp_id = 2.

```
SELECT sum(item.count) as sum FROM item, purchaseditems WHERE item.id = purchaseditems.item_id AND 
purchaseditems.comp_id= 2;
```

How can i do the same using JOIN i am new to using mysql..still a beginner in this.

could someone help me fix this. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use INNER JOIN to find the common rows between two tables matching a common column value. The below query should work for you:

> SELECT sum(item.count) FROM item JOIN purchasedItems ON item.id = purchasedItems.item_id where purchasedItems.comp_id = 2

You may read about various types of [joins](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types)

Comment: it was a typo not your mistake sorry.

Comment: can i use innerjoin on this to simplify even more?

Comment: Default JOIN is INNER JOIN in MySQL